# Can a conductor store charge?

Tags: physics

I have been taught right from highschool that a conductor can charge through conduction, induction and friction. Yet a lot of physicists challenge me that a conductor cannot store charge? Who's right and who's wrong?

Comment: My gold leaf electroscope has just stopped working.

Comment: The person with the less nuanced view of the available evidence is always wrong.

Comment: Ever heard of an ion?

Comment: The person who makes blanket generalizations is always wrong. ;-)

Comment: inductors and capacitors are made from conductors.  Is the energy stored in the conductor, and is that energy charge?

Comment: are these physicists fellow students, still learning their craft?

Comment: @dwelch, capacitors hold charges separate from each other in the presence of an electric field. Thus they have potential energy. It doesn't really matter where the charges are stored. Considering that you can make a capacitor with a vacuum dielectric,  it is certainly possible for the charges to be on the conductive electrodes. But my point is that the net charge on the whole capacitor is neutral at all times when it is used in a circuit. Could you take one apart and introduce a net charge to another circuit with an electrode that is "charged?" Maybe. That is outside of circuit analysis.

Comment: Your statements are both wrong. The first are mechanisms for imparting charge to a material (regardless of its conductance), The second is incomplete (entities in a physics approximation never exist in isolation, we are missing `in a vaccum` or `next to an infinite 2D ideal conductor` etc). If you tell the physicist this is a typical EE circuit problem, under _reasonable_ assumptions, they are right.

Answer (score 5):

When analyzing circuits with resistors, inductors, capacitors, transistors, diodes batteries, etc connected together by conductors, you should assume that none of these circuit elements can or do store any charges. If you think charges can go into one side of a conductor without an equal number of charges exiting the other side of the conductor, you will find yourself very confused and unable to analyze any circuits or have any kind of intuitive feel for how circuits work.

In real life, any object which is surrounded by a dielectric can possibly acquire a net charge (by various methods), and therefore experience electrostatic attraction or repulsion, but charge storage is not an important concept in circuit analysis.

Please note that we sometimes say that capacitors or batteries "store charge," but this is not true in the sense you are asking about. Every time a mobile charge flows into one terminal of a capacitor or battery, another one flows out the other terminal. For any circuit element with two terminals, the current flowing in is equal in magnitude to the current flowing out instantaneously at all times.

Otherwise, we would not be able to use KCL to analyze circuits.